# Flexible Content Element: section element inside another section element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I am creating an FCE for my article content.

I created sections so that I can create every article sub element multiple times in a page and every thing works fine except an image slider.

Here is my mapping :
[image]

The difference between other elements and image slider is it contains a section element inside it.

When I add and save content to image slider it simply disappear.

Rendering output shows html elements till the subsection 'Content set'.

How can I get the slider to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have bad maping set:

```
Image slider -> div (outer)
Content set -> div (inner)
Container -> li (outer)
Image -> img (outer)
```

Comment: my markup for slider is :  <div class="slider">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <img src="" alt="foo" />
          <div class="flex-caption">
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>        
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
. If I map as u said ,when each time I add a container set in the backend will result in replication of <ul>.